# ¿Cómo detecto si una columna es nula empleando Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta en Laravel Eloquent, donde se revise si la columna `deleted_at` es nula.

Intenté de esta forma, pero no funciona:

```
->whereNotNull('deleted_at')
```

Aclaro además que no estoy usando helpers de Laravel para la columna, ni siquiera los timestamps; creé el campo como cualquier otro, con `datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

En tu consulta que recibes ? un valor nulo es decir ninguna respuesta?
Quizás te falta el `->get()`

Prueba así:

```
$users = User::whereNotNull('deleted_at')->get();
```

Si sigue fallando, muestra toda la consulta que lanzas, así como el modelo y encontraremos la solución.